# find content and replace without changing numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the content without changing the number.

```
<p style="padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">6 articles</p>
```

The code below is working but the whole 6 articles are being changed by doll.

```
$("#p:contains('articles')").html("doll");
```

I also tried using this.

```
    $('p').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('dog'));
});
```

But sadly it's not working. Hope you guys can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your existing code and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: A simple lookup of docs for `replace()` would tell you it requires 2 arguments... something to replace and something to replace it with

Comment: @Taneshima, there is no id in p tag?, How does it work's

Comment: @whoami sorry i forgot to remove the id on the p tag. but regardless the whole content is changing. i want the content to be changed except the numbers.

ObsidianAge can you enlighten me more? from what i can see, the question is quite specific from the title until the sample codes i used. there's even a working code.

charlietfl i think replace is not going to work as the whole article is changing. i want to change the content without changing the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var element = $("p:contains('articles')");
element.text(element.text().replace('articles', 'doll'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have '' you can try something like this.

```
        function changeWord(newWord){
          var tmp = $('p')
          var words = tmp.text().split(" ")
          tmp.text(words[0] + newWord)
        }
```

hope this helps